# Basic BAT calculator command

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to do a very basic 2 value input BAT file but I am struggling. I used a free template from Wikihow and re-adjusted but something is not right.

I want to calculate 100/(A/B+1) and I know for a fact that the Batch calculation ignores the "+1" for some reason and basically just calculates "100/(A/B). Please help. Thanks.

```
TITLE Calculator
ECHO OFF
CLS
:TOP
color 3f
Cls
:SUM
CLS
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------
ECHO[
ECHO                 Division
ECHO[
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------
ECHO[
set /p A=" Enter First Amount = "
ECHO[
set /p B=" Enter Second Amount = "
SET /A C=100/(A/B+1)
ECHO[
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------
ECHO Result %C%
PAUSE
GOTO:TOP
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what data you input, what the results were and what your expectation was.

Comment: it doesn't ignore the `+1` in any case. probably you want floating-point division?

Comment: @Magoo
A=453
B=178
Result through script is 33%. Result manually in calculator is 28% (28.2)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, after further investigating, yes, that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an order of operations issue.

Remember that plus comes after division.

You might need this instead:

```
SET /A C=100/(A/(B+1))
```

This will allow the B+1 to come before the division.

Comment: I need A/B first. And then the result +1

Answer (score 0):

`SET /A` doesn't ignore the `+1`:

E.g. `SET /A 100/(10/2+1)` outputs `16`; the problem you most likely have is this:

> Any SET /A calculation that returns a fractional result will be
>   rounded down to the nearest whole integer.

([Source](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html))

---

However, it is possible to work around this issue:

```bat
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET /A "var=100000/(10/2+1)"
SET "fraction=%var:~-3%" & SET /A "var/=1000"
IF !fraction:~-1! GEQ 5 SET /A "fraction+=10"
SET "fraction=!fraction:~0,-1!"
ECHO %var%.%fraction%
```

Basically you multiply the number to be divided by `10^(n)` and - after you set the fraction (`%var:~-n%`) - divide it by `10^(n)` again. Then you check the last digit of the fraction for proper rounding and remove it ([read more](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)).

Comment: I don't mind that it rounds off, but the result should be 17 in this case. It's more visible with larger numbers. For example 1st amount 1447, 2nd amount 367. 

The script will give result 25, when in fact the result should be 20

Comment: @Daithí 100/6 is 16.6 repeating, correctly rounded two positions behind the decimal point it is 16.67, rounding down to the nearest whole integer is 16. Also: 1447/357 is 4.053221..., correctly rounded two positions behind the decimal point it is 4.05, rounding down to the nearest whole integer is 4. All this is correct and the script as well as `SET /A` and a normal calculator proof this.

Comment: @Daithí However, if you use the script with `SET /A "var=100000/(1447/357)"` it obiously doesn't work correctly anymore. But why would you use it that way? This is just a suggestion for better understanding and possible usage.

Comment: I basically want to convert ratio to percentage. Say the Ratio of 1447:357 equals to 4.05:1. We round it off to 4:1. A simple way to convert this ratio to percentage is to return it to a fraction. So 4:1 ratio as a fraction would be 1/5.

To get a percentange from a fraction is to divide to numenator with the denominator and then multiply the result by hundred. Or a shortcut is to use a 100 instead of 1 in the numenator.

Comment: FatalBulletHit

Example,
A=453
B=178
The script gives me the result of 33%. But manual calculation 28%. That's huge difference.

Comment: @Daithí This is not a script writing service, you should try to understand this workaround. If you think about it, you would end up with something like A*100/B instead of 100000/(A/B).

Comment: FatalBulletHit,
"But why would you use it that way?" I misunderstood the context of your rhetorical question and thought you were inquiring me why I want to use it. Obviously I know it isn't a "script writing service", if I had that mindset I wouldn't spend 2 days trying to get this work, and would have asked for a code from blank! I messed around with your code but couldn't get it to work, it's too advanced for me, as I am not a coder. But nevermind, I'll just use Excel for the calculation. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Daithí I forgot to add a link for substrings, that's on me. Take a look into [that](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) (especially the examples) and you will hopefully understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you were looking for:

```
SET /A C=(A/B)+1
SET /A C=100/(C)
```

This the correct formula, but it will not return the correct results for fractioned numbers.

So if `A = 10` and `B = 2`
`10 / 2 = 5 +1 =6`
`100/6 = 16,6` but batch rounds off to `16`.

Then `A = 453` and `B = 178`
`453 / 178 =  2,544943820224719`
`2,544943820224719 + 1 = 3,544943820224719` but Batch rounds off to `3`
`100/3 = 33`

So if you use numbers that will cause fractions, you MUST use a solution that include fractions.

Comment: No. The +1 addtion must happen before the final 100 division. So using your fisrt exaple

(10/2) = 5
5+1 = 6
100/6 = 16.6

I don't mind if its rounded off to 17

Comment: Gerhard, no, that gives completely different result, 50.
Where A=453, B=178. The result must be 28, not 50.

Comment: @Daithí Ok, so the edit is the latest, but see explanation.

Comment: Yes, I see that the rounding down the divisor messes up the result.